# Chain complexes indexed over the reals

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, order-theory

One way to think of chain complexes is as a certain subcategory of a functor category: each chain complex is a functor from $\mathbb{Z}$ regarded as a poset category to, say, abelian groups, where consecutive maps compose to 0. Is there a corresponding notion for other partially ordered categories which are not discrete, for example the real numbers, producing a sort of "continuous" complex?

Comment: Well, for instance, you could talk about a functor $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the map $F(x)\to F(x+2)$ is $0$.  I don't know why you would care about such a thing, though.  Is there some application you have in mind?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about anything in particular - mostly, it would make a chain homotopy more like an actual homotopy; further, I was vaguely inspired by categories enriched over $[0,\infty]$. It could be a pointless concept, however

Comment: Another possibility would be to require  that every composite of non-identity morphisms  in the domain is sent to $0$. In the case of $\mathbb R$, this would mean that, for each $x$, all the images at $x$ of maps from lower $x-\epsilon$ are included in all the kernels of maps to higher $x+\delta$. Then you could define homology as the intersection of all those kernels divided by the sum of all those images. But there's still @EricWofsey's question: Why would anyone care?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, that would just mean that every non-identity map goes to $0$, since they can all be decomposed as a nontrivial composition.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right. So complexes are the "same" as graded modules, and the homology of a complex is the complex itself. A nice situation for sleepy folks like me, but when I wake up I'll probably prefer non-dense (partial) orders.

Comment: If you want to compare chain homotopies with topological homotopies (as it seems like from your comment), then you should probably study model categories.